Get rid of xsi:type and use tag names instead
I have some derived classes to serialize to XML:
    public void Main()
    {
        LevelCollection collection = new LevelCollection();
        collection.Add(new SubLevel1("aaa"));
        collection.Add(new SubLevel2("bbb"));

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LevelCollection));

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, collection);
        string xml = sw.ToString();
        TestContext.WriteLine(xml);
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(SubLevel1))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(SubLevel2))]
    [XmlRoot("LevelCollection")]
    public class LevelCollection : ICollection<Level>
    {
        protected List<Level> m_Levels;

        public List<Level> Levels
        {
            get { return m_Levels; }
            set { m_Levels = value; }
        }

        public LevelCollection()
        {
            m_Levels = new List<Level>();
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public int Count 
        { 
            get { return m_Levels.Count; } 
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }

        public void Add(Level level)
        {
            m_Levels.Add(level);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            m_Levels.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(Level item)
        {
            return m_Levels.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(Level[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            m_Levels.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public IEnumerator<Level> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return m_Levels.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Remove(Level item)
        {
            return m_Levels.Remove(item);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return m_Levels.GetEnumerator();
        }

    }

    public abstract class Level 
    {

    }

    [XmlRoot("SubLevel1")]
    public class SubLevel1 : Level
    {
        public string prop1 { get; set; }

        public SubLevel1()
        {

        }

        public SubLevel1(string prop)
        {
            this.prop1 = prop;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("SubLevel2")]
    public class SubLevel2 : Level
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string prop2 { get; set; }

        public SubLevel2()
        {

        }

        public SubLevel2(string prop)
        {
            this.prop2 = prop;
        }
    }

After serialization XML looks like this (contains xsi:type attribute):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LevelCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Level xsi:type="SubLevel1">
    <prop1>aaa</prop1>
  </Level>
  <Level xsi:type="SubLevel2">bbb</Level>
</LevelCollection>

Is is possible and how to achieve the goal to change target XML to:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LevelCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SubLevel1>
    <prop1>aaa</prop1>
  </SubLevel1>
  <SubLevel2>bbb</SubLevel2>
</LevelCollection>

I cannot find the answer except to write custom writer. I wonder is it possible to remove type attribute using standard attributes.

Please edit your question, and add actual serialization code. We need a minimal reproducible example

Type is used for an inherited class.  The tag name is the base class.  XmlInclude is used for the inherited class when using xml serialization.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-8.0  So in your case the base class is Level and the inherited class is SubLevel2.  To get the results you want you cannot use xml serialization.  Or you may be able to use Ixmlserialable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-8.0

@YitzhakKhabinsky I've added serialization code

No, this is not possible with standard attributes. Use a custom writer. PS: And be prepared for the curse from those who then deserialize your XML.

@AlexanderPetrov Hmm, I seem to have seen just such looking files () and wanted to get ready to handle them.

Rather than [XmlInclude] use the polymorphism support provided by [XmlElement] and/or [XmlArrayItem].  See Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes.  Does that answer your question?

A minimal reproducible example is not provided. In such case, please try the following conceptual example. It shows how to prevent XML namespaces from showing up in the output XML.
It is heavily documented via comments in the c# code. In your code you would need to replace a correct type instead of the school type in the serialization section.
c#
void Main()
{
    string outputXML = string.Empty;

    StudentDetails s1 = new StudentDetails();
    s1.Name = "ABC"; s1.Age = 25;

    StudentDetails s2 = new StudentDetails();
    s2.Name = "DEF"; s2.Age = 35;

    School school = new School();
    school.students = new List<StudentDetails>();
    school.students.Add(s1);
    school.students.Add(s2);

    // save new XML file, serialized from classes
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";
    // to remove BOM
    settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(School));
            // to remove not needed namespaces
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            // create new XML file
            x.Serialize(xw, school, ns);
        }

        outputXML = sw.ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Classes were serialized as an XML string:{1}{0}", outputXML, Environment.NewLine);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
[XmlRoot("school")]
public class School
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "student")]
    public List<StudentDetails> students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

Output XML
<school>
  <student>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </student>
  <student>
    <Name>DEF</Name>
    <Age>35</Age>
  </student>
</school>


Unfortunately your example does not contain derived class what is the main problem. I merge my example to one piece of code.

This code with a custom writer will give you the desired result.
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


var collection = new List<Level>();
collection.Add(new SubLevel1("aaa"));
collection.Add(new SubLevel2("bbb"));

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Level>), new XmlRootAttribute("LevelCollection"));

using var writer = new CustomWriter(Console.Out);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

serializer.Serialize(writer, collection);


public class CustomWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    bool _skipAttribute = false;
    string? _prefix = null;
    string? _ns = null;

    public CustomWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer) { }
    public CustomWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding) { }
    public CustomWriter(string filename, Encoding encoding) : base(filename, encoding) { }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string? prefix, string localName, string? ns)
    {
        if (localName == "Level")
        {
            prefix = prefix;
            ns = ns;
            return;
        }
        base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string? prefix, string localName, string? ns)
    {
        if (localName == "type" && ns == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        {
            _skipAttribute = true;
            return;
        }
        base.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteString(string? text)
    {
        if (_skipAttribute)
        {
            base.WriteStartElement(_prefix, text, _ns);
            return;
        }
        base.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        if (_skipAttribute)
        {
            _skipAttribute = false;
            return;
        }
        base.WriteEndAttribute();
    }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(SubLevel1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubLevel2))]
public abstract class Level { }

public class SubLevel1 : Level
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public SubLevel1() { }
    public SubLevel1(string prop) => this.prop1 = prop;
}

public class SubLevel2 : Level
{
    [XmlText]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public SubLevel2() { }
    public SubLevel2(string prop) => this.prop2 = prop;
}

How you will deserialize such XML is another question...
